# Angular2 : read object with unknown key

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to display a specific value of different objects in a template.
The path of the value to display depends of the object.

Here a example :

```
let obj = {
    "a": "a",
    "b": {
       "1": "1",
       "2": "READ ME"
    }
}

let obj2 = {
    "x": "x",
    "y": {
       "foo": "1",
       "bar": {
           "test": "READ ME"
       }
    }
}
```

In this example I want to read the value "READ ME" like this `obj.b.2` or `obj['b']['2']` for the first object. 
However I don't know where is the READ ME value depending on objects.

To know where is located the value to display, I pass to my tempate a config array with the list of the keys to call:
like this :

```
config = ['b', '2'] // For the first object
config = ['y', 'bar', 'test'] // For the second object
```

How can I display "READ ME" in my template with my list of keys ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `reduce` function to obtain the value. You cannot define functions in your template so the logic will have to live in the component.

#### Template

```
{{config.reduce(reduceValue, obj)}}
```

#### Component

```
public reduceValue(object, prop){
    return object ? object[prop] : null;
}
```

### [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/bt3gyWvn3hWVMrpGJZzO?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Bind to a "getter" instead of directly to an array or object.

```
<div>{{ getTheRightValue ( ) }}</div>
```

In your controller:

```
get theRightValue ( ) {
   // Test objects, determine correct value...
   return theCorrectValue;
}
```

Other logic in your controller can help determine what "theCorrectValue" is as well, say for instance you get back objects from a service, when they return, do your tests and set "theCorrectValue" to whatever you need. A setter can do this nicely:

```
set theRightValue ( ) {
  // do your logic, etc...
  theCorrectValue = etc. etc.
}
```

This way you can bind to results from completely different structures. You just inspect them, set up what you need, and have that returned from the getter.